# An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends. update panel exception

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel

I'm getting this error like `An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.` i'm wondering what's wrong with my html markup :

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_AddNew" runat="server">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="template_id" runat="server" />
                     <table class="table text-center no-space table-bordered" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%">Title
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ComName1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" name="txt_ComName1"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel8" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <table>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 29%">Subscribers Category
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_subscribercategories" Width="300px" Font-Bold="false" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_subscribercategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 29%">From User </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ComName2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Width="500px" name="txt_ComName2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Img5" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/img/1398451597_Table.png" ToolTip="Select From User" Width="25px" />
                                                                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE1" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop fade in" CancelControlID="btnclose" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel_FromUser_master" TargetControlID="Img5">
                                                                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 29%">To User </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ComName3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Width="500px" name="txt_ComName3"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Img2" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/img/1398451597_Table.png" ToolTip="Select To User Subscribers" Width="25px" OnClick="Img2_Click" />
                                                                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop fade in" BehaviorID="mPopup" CancelControlID="ibtnclose" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel_Subscriber_Master" TargetControlID="hd">
                                                                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 29%">Cc </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ComName4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Width="500px" name="txt_ComName4"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Img3" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/img/1398451597_Table.png" ToolTip="Select Cc Subscribers" Width="25px" OnClick="Img3_Click" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 29%">Bcc </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ComName5" name="txt_ComName5" runat="server" Columns="10" CssClass="form-control" Rows="8" TextMode="MultiLine" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Img4" runat="server" Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/img/1398451597_Table.png" ToolTip="Select Bcc Subscribers" Width="25px" OnClick="Img4_Click" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Img6" runat="server" Height="28px" ImageUrl="~/img/20100615143456!Icon-template.png" ToolTip="Select Template" Width="23px" />
                                                                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE3" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modal-backdrop fade in" CancelControlID="ImageButton4" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel_Template_master" TargetControlID="Img6">
                                                                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_subscribercategories" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Img2" EventName="Click" />
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Img3" EventName="Click" />
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Img4" EventName="Click" />
                                                    </Triggers>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%">Email Body </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel34" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server" PasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles="False" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" name="CKEditor1"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email body is required." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 20%">Attach Files </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" CssClass="multi" />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:GridView ID="gv_file_list" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" GridLines="None">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="DeleteFile" CssClass="theme-font" Font-Underline="True" Text="x" />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("File_Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="portlet-body bordered" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_saveAsdraft" runat="server" CssClass="btn blue"
                                        OnClientClick="return validate();" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Text="Save As Draft" OnClick="btn_saveAsdraft_Click" />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="btn_save" runat="server" CssClass="btn green"
                                            OnClientClick="return validate();" ValidationGroup="AddNewMail" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_save_Click" />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_cancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn red" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btn_cancel_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_saveAsdraft" />
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_save" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_cancel" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
```

what was problem with this html markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one control as hidden field hd inside update panel 1 just put it to update panel 8 resolve this problem.